# Where can I download bitcoin core version 0.16.0

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

I changed my passphrase around march 2018 and now I can't use my new passphrase on the new bitcoin core version. When I put the back up wallet.dat into the new versions of bitcoin core, it tells something about my wallet not being compatible? So where can I download the older versions of bitcoin core, especially version 0.16.0 because it was around that time that I changed my passphrase and back up my wallet.dat. I have tried bitcoin core versions 15.1 and 16.1, but they don't work, so I think 16.0 will work because this was the time with the segwit wallet issue. Or if there is another possible solution, please let me know.
Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: What is the exact error? Different versions within the same major version (i.e. 0.16.0 and 0.16.1) will not have major changes to the wallet that make them incompatible or anything like that. If 0.16.1 can't open the wallet, then 0.16.0 won't be able to either.

Comment: So the problem really is that, I can't unlock my wallet with my correct password. I know it is the correct password because I had changed the password to a common one that I use a lot I even showed it to my wife telling her just incase she needs to access the wallet However several months afterwards,I was active with the wallet, transferring and receiving some little bits of bitcoin and then I just left the wallet for over a year and now I can't get into my wallet with my password.I am thinking that my situation is similar to this guy here,  https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/14461

Answer (score 1):

As you've explicitly asked for Bitcoin-core 0.16.0 download link, Just went through the links for version 0.16.0 under [bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.16.0/) & [bitcoincore.org](https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.16.0/) & yes, links are broken!

So, even though I agree with Andrew that you may use other minor versions (e.g. 0.16.1, 0.16.3) without any loss, but when it comes to merely helping you to download your desired version, you've got a couple of choices:

- Download the [source files](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/archive/v0.16.0.zip) & Build the client on your own
- Use the Docker container [here](https://github.com/ruimarinho/docker-bitcoin-core) & you will be up & running in minutes.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not that advance in building the client on my own. How do you do it? if it's not too hard.

Comment: With the second option (Docker container), you don't have to build the client on your own @Light, even though building a client isn't that hard, but may seem tricky to some users. So keep up with the docker option. Good luck!